Key and table reference error in MYSQL - reference error
This is my SQL query
CREATE TABLE Course (
    Cname VARCHAR(255),
    Department VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (Cname, Department)
); 

CREATE TABLE Student (
    student_id VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(255),
    last_name VARCHAR(255),
    student_email VARCHAR(255),
    student_password VARCHAR(255),
    enrollment_number INT,
    current_year INT,
    branch VARCHAR(255),
    course VARCHAR(255),
    profile_photo BLOB,
    FOREIGN KEY (course) REFERENCES Course(Cname, Department)
);

This is the error :

Error Code: 1239. Incorrect foreign key definition for 'foreign key
without name': Key reference and table reference don't match

This is the insertion (if it helps):
INSERT INTO Course (Cname, Department) VALUES
('MCA', 'NA'),
('BTECH', 'CSE'),
('BTECH', 'CIVIL'),
('BTECH', 'MECHANICAL'),
('BTECH', 'ELECTRICAL');


INSERT INTO Student (student_id, first_name, last_name, student_email, student_password, enrollment_number, current_year, branch, course, profile_photo) 
VALUES
(2320403214, 'Vivek', 'Ojha', 'ojhavivek24@gmail.com', '123', 2023, 1, 'MCA', 'NA', 'photo.png');


The number of columns in the referencing and referenced table must be the same https://dbfiddle.uk/NFvWlNhh . What were you attempting to achieve with the published code?

Your Course table have two 'PRIMARY KEY' and column CName is duplicate some where as follows:

How you want to use Course data in Student table? Think about it .
Why are you not introducing a CID column in Course table and use that column as a FOREIGN KEY in Student table.
What is purpose of this to columns in Student table according to data ?

According to data, I think branch, course are Cname, Department for Course table.
Anyway I resolve this issue after introduce a single PRIMARY KEY in Course table.
drop table if exists student;
drop table if exists Course;
-- ====================
CREATE TABLE Course (
    cid VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Cname VARCHAR(255),
    Department VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (cid)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
desc course;
INSERT INTO Course (cid, Cname, Department) VALUES
('01', 'MCA', 'NA'),
('02', 'BTECH', 'CSE'),
('03', 'BTECH', 'CIVIL'),
('04', 'BTECH', 'MECHANICAL'),
('05', 'BTECH', 'ELECTRICAL');
select * from Course;
-- ====================
CREATE TABLE Student (
    student_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(255),
    last_name VARCHAR(255),
    student_email VARCHAR(255),
    student_password VARCHAR(255),
    enrollment_number INT,
    current_year INT,
    branch VARCHAR(255),
    course VARCHAR(255),
    profile_photo BLOB,
    FOREIGN KEY (course)
        REFERENCES Course(cid)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
desc student;
INSERT INTO Student (student_id, first_name, last_name, student_email, student_password, enrollment_number, current_year, branch, course, profile_photo) 
    VALUES ('2320403214', 'Vivek', 'Ojha', 'ojhavivek24@gmail.com', 'pass123', 2023, 1, 'MCA', NULL, 'photo.png');
INSERT INTO Student
    VALUES ('2320403215', 'Jiban', 'Ojha', 'jibon@gmail.com',       'pass345', 2022, 2, 'MCA', '01', 'photo1.png');
select * from student;

Result:

 Please use the MySQL reference: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

The intention was to use the composite primary key, after this, there is only one primary key ig, cname have duplicates but the combination with department cannot be a duplicate. This is what i didn't know "The number of columns in the referencing and referenced table must be the same"
